# RewriteCond / RewreiteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I think I've got a good one here.

Trying to write a rewriterule in a .htaccess file.

If the incoming URL has **?p=** in it I need to rewrite to **index.php** .  If the incoming is the domain name only **www.myurl.com** , I need it to rewrite to **home.php** .

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

#--If the incoming url has "?p="--#
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=.* [NC]
#--Then redirect to /index.php--#
RewriteRule ^ /index.php? [NC,L,R]
#--Else, redirect to home.php--#
RewriteRule ^$ /home.php [NC,L,R]
```